# Sharing data over bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, share

I want to create an android app where I can send and receive simple strings over bluetooth. I am connecting the 2 devices manually/beforehand i.e from the settings and now want to send and receive text. I can't find a simple code to do this.

A simple and step by step explanation of the code would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html it has great information

Answer (score -1):

you can refer to bluetooth chat application from git hub .. and also google provide sample for bluetooth data transfer by using of handler in bluetooth there they use socket to set data over bluetooh please refer this link to start :
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

firstly you need bluetootchatservice.java class

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothChatService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
        UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
            mSecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
            device, final String socketType) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        bundle.putString("DEVICEADDRESS", device.getAddress());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                    mSocketType);
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private String mSocketType;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
            setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                            " socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(com.RSABluetooth.BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you can send message by creating this method in your main activity there you have to send message by converting string to byte ..
private void sendMessage(String message) {

```
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

    }
}
```

you can get response of your message in handler that you make in you main activity .. this is basic concept for sending data over blueootth and for more information please refer to google sample bluetooth application.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    if (D)
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                    switch (msg.arg1) {

                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:


                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            connection.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            connection.setText("Connecting...");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                            connection.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            connection.setText("Not connected to another device");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the buffer
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                /*
                 * SOME PRETTY IMPORTANT STUFF HERE! This is the code for read
                 */
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);


                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                    DeviceAddress = msg.getData().getString("DEVICEADDRESS");
                   /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

you can get google sample bluetooth app from above link..

Comment: I am a beginner and that code is too difficult for me to understand